# How do I architecturally Kerberize an AngularJS application with a JBoss API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jboss, kerberos

I have a nifty AngularJS application that uses a JBoss (WildFly 8) RESTful API to retrieve data. To integrate it into my corporate environment, it requires Kerberos authentication. I've see miles of documents and examples, and even some customized advice from an internal Java developer. My problem, at this time, is where in the architecture can/should the Kerberization take place?

Is it upon entry to the AngularJS app? As in do not allow unless the ticket is authorized?

Or do I challenge each API call? If this is the case, then how would I pass along the client Kerberos ticket information to the API call?

If my question sounds disjointed, or naive, it is. This is my first interaction with Kerberos.

Help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem / challenge with a PHP REST API on an Apache webserver with Kerberos auth.

Since Angular is pure client side every request is made as 'you' in Kerberos terms so you don't have to send the ticket. Your browser already sends the ticket when the request is made.

I created a login (or check logged-in) API endpoint in my PHP API which is called before every locationChange in Angular. If the login action returns false or nothing at all you are redirected to a access_denied.html page residing next to index.html (Angular).

The login action REST endpoint returns some userdata and permissions so you can do authorization.

In my case (also still searching) I also have some authorization on the API level.

Since my implementation involves a corporate webapplication I will add some code examples tomorrow ;)

Answer (score 0):

with a jboss api, it means with java code not with php and httpd in front, you can do it directly in jboss an example :

https://github.com/dstraub/spnego-wildfly

we ar doing exactly this and it works a charm, there is some example with tomcat, jboss and wildfly (different)... tell me if you have any problem... with front Angular JS and API java

Comment: I hope you can help me. I try this implementation but I use gradle instead of maven. So <artifactId> and <groupId> is of no use to me. and maven central says that package doesnt even exsit. How can I add this?

Comment: you can simply download source code directly from github, it is what i've done because i had to change some code locally... Indeed you can see how it works (create a new mechanism authentication,because wildfly 8 have deleted all authentication mechanism, just cert and basic still existing)... Wilfly 10 have embedded kerberos authentication maybe more simple like this if you can change wildlfy version. And moreOver if you want securize only a REST api you can use picketbox, or use picketLinks classes http://picketlink.org/appsecurity/rest/